# ReactiveExtensions BufferWithPredicate

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Rx has methods for *BufferWithTime*, *BufferWithCount* and *BufferWithTimeOrCount*, I want to write a BufferWithPredicate method, which would look like so:

```
public IObservable<IList<T>> BufferWithPredicate<T>(this IObservable<T> input, Func<T, IList<T>, bool> predicate)
```

Essentially, new items will be added to the existing buffer, unless the predicate returns false, in which case the buffer will be returned and a new one will be started. The predicate takes the next item, and the buffer so far as parameters.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you. I'm using Observable.Defer so that it works with cold observables as well:

```
public static class MyObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<IList<T>> BufferWithPredicate<T>(this IObservable<T> input, Func<T, IList<T>, bool> predicate)
    {
        return Observable.Defer(() =>
            {
                var result = new Subject<IList<T>>();
                var list = new List<T>();
                input.Subscribe(item =>
                    {
                        if (predicate(item, list))
                        {
                            list.Add(item);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            result.OnNext(list);
                            list = new List<T>();
                            list.Add(item);
                        }
                    }, 
                    () => result.OnNext(list));
                return result;
            });
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var observable = new[] { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15 }.ToObservable();
var result = observable.BufferWithPredicate((item, list) => item % 2 == 0);
result.Subscribe(l => Console.WriteLine("New list arrived. Count = {0}", l.Count));
```

Output:

```
"New list arrived. Count = 6" 
"New list arrived. Count = 3"
```

Comment: Aha, I didn't know Observable had some methods which weren't extensions of IObservable! My one issue with this: does it leak subscriptions because it subscribes to the input but never returns the disposable which allows you to destroy subscriptions?

Comment: Nope. This returns a deferred observable - if you don't subscribe, it will go out of scope and get garbage collected. If you subscribe, the normal rules apply: call Dispose on the returned object, or wait until OnCompleted fires; either one will ensure no memory leaks.